# Batch class of managed package is not processing

Tags: apex, app

I have a batch class in a managed package that sync data in salesforce with other app.
I installed this managed package in diff Salesforce orgs. In some it is working fine and in one org this is not working, showing 'Processing'.

What can be the reason.
Can someone help me on this...

Thanks,
Mahi

Comment: Have you cancelled the batch and tried re-running it to see if it works when re-run? as you mentioned that it syncs data with another app, i would also look into making sure that the 'connection' between these two has been setup correctly.

Comment: Yes Michael, I have re run the batch class many times and also check the connection.everything is fine.

Comment: Unless you're receiving logs, or have code that you can share there's not much we can help with. Managed packages are created by a person or company, they should be able to help you out.

Comment: What package is this ? Do you get any logs ? Screenshot ?  The less details you share with us, the harder it is to help.

Comment: Are there any configuration steps that have to be performed before the package works? Some field mapping for example. Maybe it has to be somehow activated (license matters). If it's "processing" at least in theory you should see numbers going up / more spawned jobs. Try attaching debug logs?

Comment: I was working on this managed package and installed in this org. I made some changes in the batch class and it run.......    Thanks for the reply